# How to get the element inputName through ng-messages directive?

Tags: angularjs

how do I trigger the error messages without knowing the input name? See the code below:

```
<input class="form-control"
            id="{{field.field_id}}"
            set-name="{{field.field_id}}"
            type="text"
            ng-model="field.field_value"
            ng-minlength="field.field_char_num_min"
            ng-maxlength="field.field_char_num_max"/>

    <div ng-messages="don't know the input name yet" class="my-messages">
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
        <div ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
    </div>
```

In `ng-messages` should be written the path to errors from the input, like `myForm.inputName.$error`. But the Inputs will be generated and appended automatically so I  can't write the name because a generator sets the names. I have to get a hold of the input name. How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried: `myForm[field.field_id].$error`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in in ng-message

```
<form name="formName">
<input type="text" id="anyName"  name="anyName"  required/>
  <span ng-show="formName.anyName.$error.required"> Please enter a value.</span>                            
</form>
```

Comment: but I don't know what is the name of the input so I cant write it. The name is generated as random characters for each new appended input.

Comment: can you provide plunker please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `field[field.field_id]['$invalid']` to determine whether field is valid or not, and then by using `field[field.field_id]['$error']` show `minlength` & `maxlength` error

**Markup**

```
<div ng-show="field[field.field_id]['$invalid']" class="my-messages">
    <div ng-message="field[field.field_id]['$error'].minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    <div ng-message="field[field.field_id]['$error'].maxlength">Your field is too long</div>
</div>
```